# What are the main differences between the ed and the ex editor?

Tags: ed, ex

The `ex` editor is often touted as an enhancement and simplification of `ed`. I would like to know what specific enhancements and simplifications it offers. GNU `ed`, for example, offers extended regular expressions. So, besides these, what advantages come with `ex`? I am thinking specifically of the original `ex` editor by Bill Joy, not later incarnations in Vim.

Comment: This is a rather big question and depends on what implementation of `ex` you're looking at (I mean, Vim in `ex` mode is pretty much a totally different editor compared to what the POSIX standard prescribes for `ex`, and the difference between that and `ed` are simply too numerous to list). Also, "advantages" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: You could start with the `ex` man page from 2BSD in 1979.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a very rough first approximation we can say that `ed` doesn't show what has been modified (until asked to `print`) and ex could (additionally) work as a full screen editor. Using a very old description from the the posix spec:

- [ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html)

> The ed utility is a line-oriented text editor that uses two modes: command mode and input mode. In command mode the input characters shall be interpreted as commands, and in input mode they shall be interpreted as text.

- [ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html)

> The ex utility is a line-oriented text editor. There are two other modes of the editor-open and visual-in which screen-oriented editing is available.

Both programs have been extended, modified and improved over the years and now the list of differences is much longer and impossible to fully list on a short answer of this site.

That `full-screen` capability has lead to the development of `vi` (a visual editor), and then to `vim` (visual improved).